# How to keep views in scrollview (that are inside a linear layout) that are not visible from being created?

Tags: android

I have linear layout inside a scrollview, and i would like to keep those views which are not visible(which are inside the linear layout) from being created until they are either visible or near to being visible. Like adjacent to one that is visible.  I don't know if for example if turning off visibility will keep the View from being created(in terms of resources), or if gone could be used.

Update: The reason I am asking this question is because scrolling is taking a heck of a long time when there are say 30 view elements in the linear layout.  These are not large view elements either, about what you would find for a record in a listview.  I should add that the whole scrollview is inside a fragment.

Thanks

Comment: You'd only be able to tell that they were near to being drawn by knowing their height. You can query the height only after they've been created. Perhaps you can add some more information about the type of content you're looking to show here (is it a list of data items that all follow a similar format/from a single source?).

Comment: Please note I just updated. The Linear Layout is inside a scrollview, it has a bunch of various views (hence not a listview), and it I don't want the ones drawn that not visible or near to being visible. Could gone, or visible be used or would it be necessary to use a View holder pattern.

Comment: Why does it matter when the views inside your LinearLayout are created?

Comment: Setting visibility to `gone` or `invisible` won't make a difference - the view will still be created. It's difficult to recommend options without understand the purpose for your wanting to do this (I appreciate you tried to give minimal knowledge to make the issue as small as possible, but sometimes it's more helpful to be slightly verbose in describing your problem).

Comment: @mpellegr Why does it matter? Because scrolling now takes a long time if there are say 30 elements

Comment: Unless they were very staggered, I'd try to somehow fit them in logical blocks and use a listview. Being able to use any arbitrary view as a listitem is really flexible if you get creative, and it'll be faster than a scrollview in any case.

Comment: Nevertheless I would like to know how to control or at least have some effect on when a view is created/destroyed inside this scenario. Scrollviews exist and I happen to be using one.

Comment: @TestBest I'd venture to guess that in general, any situation where you needed to control when a view is created/destroyed you aren't using the platform correctly in some way. Either you should create a different design flow and place some of those elements in a dialog or another activity. Or, which is probably applies in this case, generalize the elements in your LinearLayout and see if they can't be put into a ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a LinearLayout(vertical) with 30 children. If you scroll to the bottom, which views would then be "created"?

- If only the visible(or near visible) ones, then you can't measure how far down in the scroll they will be any more.
- If at that point you're just saying you should create them when they *first* appear, and stay around afterward, that *could* work. However, once you scroll around some, you'll still have a bunch of views, and the same problem you have now.

---

> Scrollviews exist and I happen to be using one.

True, but that doesn't necessarily means it's the best tool for the job. I tried something similar with my first Android project. I didn't know much about ListViews, and ended up rolling my own adapter that sounds eerily similar to what you're doing.

Long story short, the performance was bad. It **did** work, but once I(finally) switched  to a ListView, the difference was nothing short of amazing. I'm just trying to keep others from going down that road. It was days of wasted time trying to get it "just right".